# Parallax Scrolling with CSS

Tags: css, background, html

Can parallax scrolling be added to a webpage using CSS only.  Without using javascript or jquery.  And with banded sections altering the color of the non scrolling background as the page moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  See this page for a working example and included source code:  [Creating Scrolling Parallax Effects with CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/parallax)

Eg....

**HTML**

```
<article>  <div class="parallax">    <div class="bg__foo">foo</div>    <div class="bg__bar">bar</div>    <div class="bg__baz">baz</div>    <div class="bg__bazz">bazz</div>  </div>  <header>    <h1>Example for 'background-attachment : fixed'</h1>    <h2><a href="https://twitter.com/stefanjudis">@stefanjudis</a></h2>    <p>Image by <a href="http://matty4z.deviantart.com/art/mlp-lil-stream-351612016">Matty4z</a></p>  </header>  <section>    <div class="container">      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>    </div>  </section>  <section class="parallax">    <div class="bg__break">      <div class="capture">Caption for this beautiful break image, Caption for this beautiful break image, Caption for this beautiful break image, Caption for this beautiful break image.</div>    </div>  </section>  <section>    <div class="container">      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>    </div>  </section></article>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parallax [class*="bg__"] {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax [class*="bg__"]:nth-child(2n) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
}
.parallax .bg__foo, .parallax .bg__bazz {
  height: 100vh;
}
.parallax .bg__foo {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
}
.parallax .bg__bar {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax2.jpg);
}
.parallax .bg__baz {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax3.jpg);
}
.parallax .bg__bazz {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
}
.parallax .bg__break {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
}
.parallax .capture {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: -1.5em 1em 0 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  background: rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0.125em #333;
}

article .container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
article header {
  position: relative;
  margin: -5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
article h1, article h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.333em;
}
article section {
  padding: 3em;
}
article section.parallax {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #f66;
}
```